# How to change a value using `sub`

Tags: r

I have a data frame in R called `channelsplit` and I want to change the name of one my segments '(Other)' to 'Affiliates'.

```
channelGrouping    sessions
1   (Other)        33438
2   Direct         38358
3   Display        6903
4   Email          20
5   Organic Search 99450
6   Paid Search    803
7   Referral      58806
8   Social        52619
```

My code using the sub function is:

```
channelsplit$channelGrouping<-sub("(other)", "", "Affiliates","channelsplit$channelGrouping")
```

But I get:

```
channelGrouping sessions
1   Affiliates  33438
2   Affiliates  38358
3   Affiliates   6903
4   Affiliates     20
5   Affiliates  99450
6   Affiliates    803
7   Affiliates  58806
8   Affiliates  52619
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to bring `sub()` into this. Use resources around [recoding data in R](http://rprogramming.net/recode-data-in-r/).

```
channelsplit$channelGrouping[channelsplit$channelGrouping == "(Other)"] <- "Affiliates"
```

Comment: It may not work if `channelsplit$channelGrouping` of class `factor`.

Comment: @DavidArenburg True, in that case, I'd still opt for something other than `sub()` -- perhaps `plyr::revalue(channelsplit$channelGrouping, c("(Other)"="Affiliates"))` or `plyr::mapvalues`.

Answer (score 2):

`(` is stored meta-character in regex. In order to tell `sub` to literaly search for `(`, the easiest way would be to specify `fixed = TRUE`. You are also passing too many variables into `sub` and you shouldn't quote your `x` variable.

```
sub("(Other)", "Affiliates", channelsplit$channelGrouping, fixed = TRUE)
# [1] "Affiliates"     "Direct"         "Display"        "Email"          "Organic Search"
# [6] "Paid Search"    "Referral"       "Social"
```